# Continuous function satisfying three properties

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

I'm searching for a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ satisfying

- $f$ is continuous and positive,
- $\lim_{(\epsilon,\delta)\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\epsilon,\delta)}{\epsilon\delta} =0$
- f(0,0)=0 is the unique minimum of $f$ (and thus unique zero).

Can you provide an analytical expression for such a function?

Comment: @StinkingBishop check the 3rd point about the unique minimum.

Comment: If $f(0,0)=0$, the function is not 'positive'.

Comment: I'd say that forbidding the function to have zeros and be positive would be requiring it to be _strictly_ positive. Anyhow what i meant is $f(x,y)\ge 0, \ \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What does $\approx$ mean in this context? The same as $\sim$ in http://web.mit.edu/broder/Public/asymptotics-cheatsheet.pdf ?

Comment: You are right, I was not precise enough. I'll update the property

Comment: So I suppose you really meant $f(\epsilon,\delta)=o(\epsilon\delta)$ when $(\epsilon,\delta)\to(0,0)$, is that right? (What you wrote is not really defined in neighbourhoods of $(0,0)$ due to zero in the denominator.)

Comment: I thought limits where invented exactly as a way to analyze the behaviour of function at points which yield undefined expressions in traditional algebra, e.g. $\frac{1}{0}$, so I don't understand the point about the zero in the denominator. What I'm saying is that, whatever path $(\epsilon(t),\delta(t))$ you choose to approach the origin, the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\epsilon(t),\delta(t))}{\epsilon(t)\delta(t)}$ always yields the same value. This, as I recall, is the definition of a well-defined limit at a point.

Comment: This is not the same as the double limit $(\epsilon,\delta)\to(0,0)$. See my answer below for the double limit (restricted to the domain where $\epsilon,\delta\ne 0$). The question about path-wise limit may have a different answer altogether.

Comment: @Tanatofobico: here is what Stinking Bishop means. The definition of the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)\to(a,b)$ requires that $f(x,y)$ be defined in some deleted neighborhood around $(a,b)$. In other words, we assume there is an $r$ so that $f$ is defined for all $(x,y)$ satisfying $\color{red}{0<}|(x,y)-(a,b)|<r$ (which is a "deleted" nbhd, because the $\color{red}{0<}$ forces us to delete the point $(a,b)$ from the nbhd). Your expression $\frac{f(x,y)}{xy}$ is not defined on any such deleted neighborhood of $(0,0)$, though. That's because any such nbhd contains points where $x,y$ are zero.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thanks for clarifying this for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such function. Suppose the second condition is valid: this would mean that, for some $C>0$, $|f(\epsilon,\delta)|<|\epsilon\delta|$ for all $\epsilon$, $\delta$ satisfying  $0<|\epsilon|,|\delta|<C$. Now fix one such $\epsilon\ne 0$, and let $\delta\to 0$: from continuity of $f$ we have that $|f(\epsilon, 0)|\le 0$, which would imply that $f(\epsilon, 0)=0$ - contradictory with $(0,0)$ being a unique minimum.